# Filter array in second controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter an array in Controller2 by clicking a button with an id in controller1. This is the code i've come up with so far, but I'm confused how to pass the id parameter to the factory, filter the list and update the scope in controller2.

```
<div id="parentpage">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl1" id="div1">
        <a href="#" ng-click="buttonclick(1)">Filter list with id 1</a>
        <a href="#" ng-click="buttonclick(2)">Filter list with id 2</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('div1'), ['app']);
    </script>

    <div ng-controller="ctrl2" id="div2">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.id}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('div2'), ['app']);
    </script>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('factory', function($http, $q){
    var factory = {};

    factory.getItems = function() { 
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('someRestService').success(function (result){
            deferred.resolve(result);
        })

        return deferred.promise;
    }
});

app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope, factory){
    $scope.buttonclick = function(id) {
        //filter items in ctrl2 based on id
    }
});

app.controller('ctrl2', function($scope, factory){
    $scope.items = factory.getItems();
    $scope.items.then(function (items) {
        $scope.items = items;
    })
});
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: One comment for future readers. This won't work with using angular.bootstrap twice. It looks likes this instantiates two versions of the same app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to make a `factory` which can then amend the values in which are in turn bound to the `$scope` in `ctrl2` like this:

```
<div ng-app="app" id="parentpage">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl1" id="div1"> <a href="#" ng-click="buttonclick(1)">Filter list with id 1</a>
 <a href="#" ng-click="buttonclick(2)">Filter list with id 2</a>
 <a href="#" ng-click="buttonclick()">Clear Filter</a>

    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl2" id="div2">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in items()">{{i.id}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note how the ng-repeat is `i in items()` which allows you to keep track of the updated set of `items` in the factory.  This runs the `getItems` function which returns the value of `myItems` from the `factory`.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('testFactory', function () {
    var myOriginalItems = [{
        id: 1
    }, {
        id: 2
    }, {
        id: 3
    }, {
        id: 4
    }, {
        id: 5
    }];

    var myItems = myOriginalItems;

    return {
        setItems: function (id) {
            if (typeof id == 'undefined') {
                myItems = myOriginalItems;
            } else {
                myItems = [{
                    id: id
                }];
            }
            return myItems;
        },
        getItems: function () {
            return myItems;
        }
    };

});

app.controller('ctrl1', function ($scope, testFactory) {
    $scope.buttonclick = function (id) {
        testFactory.setItems(id);
    };
});

app.controller('ctrl2', function ($scope, testFactory) {
    $scope.items = testFactory.getItems;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4veqjzdu/

Comment: Ok, figured it out. Create an empty array items outside the function. initialize it as an empty array. And when the async call returns, update the items array. And the $scope is udpated as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MartijnE You should also be able to return your promise as in your original question.

Comment: I've tried returning a promise as used in my example, and that didn't work. Angular was complaining that there were was no length property (or something else) on the object building the view (I forgot the actual error message). That's why I created an empty array.

Comment: @MartijnE Here's an example of a service http://jsfiddle.net/kthmysq6/ and a factory http://jsfiddle.net/jcwphoq3/ both using ngMock to simulate a 2500 millisecond delay in retrieving the values.

Comment: Thanks for the example.