# How to double bind?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I`m new to angularJS. I have a table, I make a request and output some default data in my tablerows from Controller2. Now I want to make a different request and output other data in the same table,but this time from Controller1. How can I do this ?

**Html**

```
 <tr ng-repeat="stats in statsFromTable" ng-show="statsFromTable.length > 0">
     <td><span ng-bind="stats.PERS"></span></td>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 Controller2 -- > $scope.statsFromTable = data.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES.historyList; // the first default request
 Controller1 -- > ???
```

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091875/filter-array-in-second-controller it shows how to bind 2 controllers via a service/factory

Comment: You don't "double bind"! Don't think in terms of adding to a view. The view only reflects what the internal state (the `$scope`) looks like. What you need to do is have exactly *one* property on your `$scope` which holds the data. The table will reflect the contents of that property. What you need to do is *add data to that property*.

Comment: Also, `ng-show="statsFromTable.length > 0"` is superfluous.

Comment: Try storing your data in a service, which can then be passed to both controllers.

Comment: @all thanks for the reply, I managed to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use $rootScope to share info between controllers. For that purpouse you can use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

So your code could look like:

```
angular.
 module('yourAngularModule', []).
  controller('MyController', ['$scope','myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.number1 = myService.number;
  }]).
  controller('MyController2', ['$scope','myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.number2 = myService.number;
  }]).
 service('myService', [function() {
    var service = {
      number:0
    };
   return service;

  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

And then you could bind the data like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <h3>Controller 1</h3>
    {{number1}}  // Will display service.number --> 0
</div>

<div ng-controller="MyController2">
    <h3> Controller 2</h3>
    {{number2}} //  Will display service.number --> 0
</div>
```

I [did a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fk4dUPMQx6tQtUuGSuqc?p=preview) where you can take a look at how two different controllers share info via service.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply and advice !!

Answer (score -3):

you can use $rootScope to do this. here is the [example demo](http://goo.gl/wtb06q) for you i have created

Comment: One should [avoid polluting the $rootscope](http://michaeleconroy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/dont-dirty-up-rootscope-create-global.html) by, for instance, creating a service.